# Add a static page in squarespace developer mode locally

Tags: squarespace

I set up a local environment for my squarspace site and its working fine.

I followed these instructions  https://developers.squarespace.com/static-pages/ and I have double checked the file extensions and it is set up correctly.

From inside the CMS I created a page named Movies and this is a screenshot of my files/path.
[image]

[image]

but still cant get anything to display on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you may consider avoiding the use of capital letters in your file names, such as the "M" on "Movies". In developer mode, some (but not all) types of files will not work properly unless all lower-case letters are used. I have not tested this with static page files; this is just a precautionary suggestion.

Second, you said *"From inside the CMS I created a page named Movies..."*. However, static pages are not created within the backend CMS UI. Rather, once you add your `.page.conf` and `.page` files to your local repository, you must then push them to your live site at Squarespace. Then, refresh the page where you're viewing the backend UI. The static page should appear on its own in the "Not Linked" section. It should look something like this, though perhaps it is at the bottom of that section.

[image]

Although counter intuitive, only after doing that will your page appear when browsing from the local development server.

Comment: I still would need to push them to my live site even though I am working locally?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, @Carter . This has to do with how the local server environment pulls data from the live server in order to display your site locally. It's not great, and is something that occurs in other contexts when working with Squarespace developer mode too.

Comment: thank you that worked... should should help with the squarespace documentation